# Reading a local text file from a local javascript file?

Tags: javascript, file, text

I'm using the following code to read a local text file from a local Javascript file, but it isn't working:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open('GET', fileLocation, true);
```

The error I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/File.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access local resources from javascript,
You should put this file in your site and try to access it via fileLocation like http://mywebsite/File.txt

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

```
var fileContent='';
var theLocation='';

function readFileViaApplet(n) {
 document.f1.t1.value='Reading in progress...';
 document.ReadURL.readFile(theLocation);
 setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);
}

function showFileContent() {
 if (document.ReadURL.finished==0) {
  setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);
  return;
 }
 fileContent=document.ReadURL.fileContent;
 document.form1.textarea1.value=fileContent;
}
```