# javascript, how could we read a local text file with accent letters into it?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have one doubt because I need to read a local file and I have been studying some threads, and I have seen various ways to handle it, in most of the cases there is an input file.

I would need to load it directly through code.

I have studied this thread:

[How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

And I could read it.

The surprising part was when I tried to split the lines and words, it showed: � replacing accent letters.

The code I have right now is:

myFileReader.js

```
function readTextFile(file) {

    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log('The complete text is', allText);
                let lineArr = intoLines(allText);
                let firstLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[0]);
                let secondLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[1]);

                console.log('Our  first line is: ', lineArr[0]);

                let atlas = {};
                for (let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the first line is : ${firstLineWords[i]}`);
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the SECOND line is : ${secondLineWords[i]}`);
                    atlas[firstLineWords[i]] = secondLineWords[i];
                }
                console.log('The atlas is: ', atlas);
                let atlasJson = JSON.stringify(atlas);
                console.log('Atlas as json is: ', atlasJson);

                download(atlasJson, 'atlasJson.txt', 'text/plain');
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}

function download(text, name, type) {

    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = name;
}

function intoLines(text) {
    // splitting all text data into array "\n" is splitting data from each new line
    //and saving each new line as each element*

    var lineArr = text.split('\n');

    //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as below


    return lineArr;


}

function intoWords(lines) {


    var wordsArr = lines.split('" "');


    return wordsArr;

}
```

***The doubt is: how could we handle those special character which are the vowels with accent?***

I ask this, because even in the IDE thet interrogation marks appeared if we load the txt in UTF-8, so then I changed to ISO-8859-1 and it loaded well.

Also I have studied:

[Read UTF-8 special chars from external file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354213/read-utf-8-special-chars-from-external-file-using-javascript)

[Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

[Reading a local text file from a local javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976911/reading-a-local-text-file-from-a-local-javascript-file)

**In addition, could you explain if there is a shorter way to load files in client javascript. For example in Java there is the FileReader / FileWriter / BufferedWriter. Is theren in Javascript something similar?**

Thank you for you help!

Comment: *"In addition..."* On SO, it's important to ask ask **one** question/question, not two (or more). (I was about to link to the help page that says that and...I'm not finding one. Which is a problem with the help. :-) )

Comment: The first step in accepting a text file is knowing which character encoding it uses.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the file is encoded with ISO-8859-1 (or possibly the very-similar Windows-1252).

There's no BOM or equivalent for those encodings.

The only solutions I can see are:

1. Use a (local) server and have it return the HTTP `Content-Type` header with the encoding identified as a charset, e.g. `Content-Type: text/plain; encoding=ISO-8859-1`
2. Use UTF-8 instead (e.g., open the file in an editor as ISO-8859-1, then save it as UTF-8 instead), as that's the [default encoding](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#document-response) for XHR response bodies.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your text in an `.html` file with the corresponding content type,
   for example:

   ```html
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
   ```

   enclose the text between two tags ("####" in my example)  (or put in a div)
2. Read the html page, extract the content and select the text:

   ```js
    window.open(url); //..
    var content = newWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    var strSep="####";
    var x = content.indexOf(strSep);
    x=x+strSep.length;    
    var y = content.lastIndexOf(strSep); 
    var points=content.slice(x, y);
   ```